# Basic blur event in a Telerik Nativescript Mobile App

Tags: javascript, mobile, telerik, nativescript

I am writing a cross-platform mobile app using Telerik AppBuilder with NativeScript. I am going nuts trying to figure out how to get a basic "blur" or "onTextChanged" event on a TextField. I can figure out how to do things like "tap" events, but then why is it so hard to find a sample of someone doing "blur" or "onTextChanged"?

I've tried this:

```
var tagField = view.getViewById(page, "tfDescription")
tagField.set("onblur", function(eventData) {
    pageData.set("debug", "blur this field: " + JSON.stringify(eventData));    
});
```

I've also tried every attribute I can think of in the xml:

```
<TextField id="tfDescription" blur="blur" onblur="blur" onLoseFocus="blur" focusLost="blur" textChanged="blur" row="2" text="{{ description }}" />
```

None of these work. Does anyone have any clue how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know there no blur(-like) event in NativeScript. However, you can react to when text is changed.

What you want to do is to utilize the [Data Binding Mechanisms](https://docs.nativescript.org/bindings.html) and the 
 [Observable Object](https://docs.nativescript.org/ApiReference/data/observable/HOW-TO.html) in NativeScript.

Briefly, data binding will allow you to connect the user interface (most often described in your XML files) with your business model/data object. A data binding can be "one way" meaning that any changes you do in your data object will be reflected in the UI. It can also be two ways meaning that any changes you do in the UI will also be reflected back in your data object.

In your case, you want two way bindings as you want whatever happens in the UI (user input text) to be reflected in your model.

#### Example

**xml**

Let's say you have this xml:

```
<Page xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" loaded="pageLoaded">
 <StackLayout>
   <TextField text="{{ description }}" />
 </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

**js**

I've commented inline for easier understanding.

```
var observable = require("data/observable");

function pageLoaded(args) {
    var page = args.object;

    /**
     * Creating a new Observable object.
     */
    var contextObj = new observable.Observable();

    /**
     * Setting the property 'description' to 'hi there'.
     * In your XML you'll attach this property to the
     * Text field as such:
     * <TextField text="{{ description }}" />
     * This means that the Text field will, by default
     * be prepopulated with 'Hi there'
     */
    contextObj.set("description", "Hi there");

    /**
     * Attaching the observable object to the
     * 'bindingContext' of the page. This is a
     * special property to which you want to attach
     * the object. By default bindings are two way.
     */
    page.bindingContext = contextObj;

    /**
     * Event listener.
     * When the user is changing the text in the UI, this gets propagated down
     * to the contextObj which will change. Here we add an event listener for
     * changes and log some information about the change that just happened.
     */
    contextObj.addEventListener(observable.Observable.propertyChangeEvent, function (event) {
        console.log('The object changed!');
        console.log('Event:        ' + event.eventName);
        console.log('propertyName: ' + event.propertyName);
        console.log('New value:     ' + event.value);
        console.log('');
    });

 }
 exports.pageLoaded = pageLoaded;
```

Comment: This was the conclusion that I was starting to come to. However, there are two problems with this. First, I need to know when the textbox is blurred because I want certain events to trigger when this happens. For example, I want to save the results of the changed textbox to a cloud service. Second, if I bind to the text change, again, I run into the problem of not knowing when the user is done changing the text. I don't want EVERY character change ... I just want to know when they are finished changing a description so I can save the results without forcing them to tap a "save" button.

Ideas?

Comment: Do you have any idea why I keep getting this error whenever I try to add an event listener? I've used the example you just gave me before, and have had this problem before now as well: "/app/tns_modules/data/observable/observable.js:32 TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'eventNames.split')

Comment: I'd probably make the updated on page `navigatedFrom` and/or set an timeout and updated every X seconds changes are made since last. However, you could implement a blur function yourself if you know your way around iOS/Android, as you've direct access to the APIs.

Comment: About the error, no idea. I'd update my tns_modules to bleeding edge and see if the error persist. To do that, follow the _Using the Latest tns_modules_ guide here: http://docs.nativescript.org/running-latest

Comment: "However, you could implement a blur function yourself if you know your way around iOS/Android, as you've direct access to the APIs" - Way too new at this. This is my first foray into mobile development since I took a Mobile Development on the Android Platform class to wrap up my master's degree 4 years ago. I had hoped to use Telerik as an easy way of breaking into mobile cross-platform, and then expand my knowledge as I went. I think your idea with a timeout is probably the way to go given my current skill level. Thanks a lot for your help on this!

Comment: I was able to figure out the problems I was having in the comment above (not the original question in this post), and posted it as a separate solution below. I just wanted to put a comment here to draw attention to it.

Answer (score 1):

FYI in NativeScript 3 the `blur` event has been added and can be used with either `TextView` or `TextField` components.

Edit there's now also a `focus` event about to be merged from [this pull request](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/pull/4730).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm not marking this as the correct solution, but it will be helpful if anyone sees this. In Telerik, NativeScript appears to have some subtle differences. You will need to learn to read the library files, such as tns_modules/data/observable/observable.js in order to figure these things out on your own. For example, to create a property change listener, this is the syntax you need to use:

```
    pageData.on(observableModule.knownEvents.propertyChange, function(propertyChangeData){
        if (propertyChangeData.propertyName != "debug"){
            pageData.set("debug", propertyChangeData.propertyName + " has been changed and the new value is: " + propertyChangeData.value);
        }
    });
```

Note that you use "observableModule.knownEvents.propertyChange" instead of "observable.Observable.propertyChangeEvent". You don't have to use the function "on" instead of "addEventListener" as I've done. The function "on" literally just turns around and calls "addEventListener".

I hope this helps someone out there.

Answer (score 0):

In nativescript 3+ this is how I catch blur events.

The sample code is in nativescript (core)

**example.js**

```
const view = require("ui/core/view");
const textFieldModule = require("ui/text-field");

exports.pageLoaded = (args) => {
  let page = args.object;
  let myTextFieldView = view.getViewById(page, "myTextField");
  myTextFieldView.on(textFieldModule.TextField.blurEvent, function(eventData) {
      console.log('blur event triggered');
  }, this);
}
```

**example.xml**

```
<Page loaded="pageLoaded">
  ...
  <TextField
    id="myTextField"
    hint="My Text Field"
    text="{{ myTextField }}" />
  ...
</Page>
```