# Nativescript - TextField lose-focus event

Tags: nativescript

In {N}, I've got a TextField and would like to call a function when the focus is lost.

I've looked at the returnPress event - but that doesn't seem to be invoked on losing focus.

I've got text="{{ property }}" set - it gets called on every key input. I just need it at the end of the input.

Comment: See : http://stackoverflow.com/a/30506380/6449750

Answer (score 3):

A little while ago I added the `blur` event so you can now do `blur="{{ onBlur }}"` or `(blur)="onBlur()"` in case you're working on an Angular app.

And just so you know, there's currently a [PR pending](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/pull/4730) to add the `focus` as well.

Both of these are/will be available for `TextField` and `TextView`.

Answer (score 0):

Here how you can envoke function as soon as you press the return key from keyboard -

```
<TextField #secondTx hint="Phone*" row="1" colspan="4" autocorrect="false" returnKeyType="done" (returnPress)="YourFunction(secondTx.text)" [(ngModel)]="phoneNumber" keyboardType="phone" ></TextField>
```

Let me know if it doesn't work! Thanks